# Extract and add sub strings into strings

Tags: string, excel, vba

The context here is that I'm trying to identify phone number patterns of a big messy column, and format them as this:

(CC) NNNN-NNNN

CC being two digit area code

There may be two or more numbers in the same cell(They need to remain in the same cell unfortunately), and need to be as follow :

(CC) NNNN-NNNN / (CC) NNNN-NNNN

The numbers are just raw digits, no spaces or characters, but are as TEXT and need to remain so because of the 15 digit limit on Excel

Now, I'm having problem with two cases

Case 1:

Two phones and one area code (18 digits)

Example : CCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN

**What I need is a function that takes the first two characters from this string and add them at the eleventh spot of said string, resulting in a 20 char string**

Case 2:

One phone and two same area code(12 digits)

CCCCNNNNNNNN

This one just need to remove the first two characters

Tried this way for case 1, but ended up with a 22 string char? not sure where I went wrong

```
            s1 = Mid(Cells(j, 3), 1, 2)
            s2 = Mid(Cells(j, 3), 3, 10)
            s3 = Mid(Cells(j, 3), 11, 18)
            s4 = s1 & s2 & s1 & s3
```

Comment: "I'm having problem with two cases" - what is the problem ? which programming language are you using ? what have you tried ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the correct tags

Comment: Why is this tagged as VBA? I see no VBA code in your question.

Comment: It seems to be extremely straight forward (using `Mid` to extract and `&` to concatenate). What have you tried?

Comment: @JohnColeman Tried what you said, unexpected result, edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

The big caveat here is the formatting of the existing data....  how do you know what digits are "area code" and what digits are phone number?  You can do what you are trying to do here with Excel formulas without any VBA...  For Case 1 you can use the formula below, replacing "A1" with the appropriate cell reference.

```
    ="("&MID(A1, 1, 2)&") "&mid(A1,3,4)&"-"&mid(a1,7,4)&" / ("&MID(A1, 1, 2)&") "&mid(A1,11,4)&"-"&mid(a1,15,4)
```

For Case 2 you can use the formula below.

```
    ="("&MID(A1, 1, 2)&") "&mid(A1,5,4)&"-"&mid(a1,9,4)
```

Does your solution *have* to be in vba?

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter in `Mid` is the *length* of the extracted substring, not its final index. If it is omitted - the selection goes to the end of the string. The selection also goes to the end of the string if the length parameter exceeds the number of possible characters. `s2 = Mid(Cells(j, 3), 3, 10)` was thus of length `10` rather than the expected `8`. Your case 1 would look something like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As String, t As String
    s = "CCNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN"
    t = Mid(s, 1, 10) & Mid(s, 1, 2) & Mid(s, 11)
    Debug.Print t
End Sub
```

Which has output:

```
CCNNNNNNNNCCNNNNNNNN
```

Answer (score 0):

For your two cases:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=18,REPLACE(A1,11,0,LEFT(A1,2)),IF(LEN(A1)=12,MID(A1,3,10)))
```

Not knowing the other formats or desired results, it is hard to expand on the formula.  The formula will return `FALSE` if the length is other than 12 or 18.